# Using run script to compare values from info.plist

Tags: xcode, shell

I have two values in my info.plist file let's say string1 , string 2

I want to add a run script that compare the two values and invoke a build error if the values are not equal.

I'm new to scripting to I'm facing some syntax issues, here's what I've accomplished so far

```
set string1 to $(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print string1" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
set string2 to $(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print string2" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")

echo string1
echo string2

if string1 = string2 then
echo "no errors" else
echo "generate build error in xcode"
```

Any pointers are highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error you are facing its because of wrong syntax in if else loop and setting value to the variables

```
# Basic value settings to the variable from the command execution
string1=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print string1" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
string2=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print string2" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")

#Below is the basic if else loop in shell scripting with string comparison
if [ "$string1" = "$string2" ]
then
    echo "EQUAL"
else
    echo "NOT EQUAL"
fi
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's working, my syntax was completely missed up. do you know how can I force the build operation to fail in case the strings are not equal  ?

Comment: @ahmad: Don't know the specifics of interaction with Xcode, but in general you indicate an error through a **non-zero (> 0) exit code**: `exit 1`, for instance (not having an explicit `exit` statement returns the last command's exit code - 0, if it succeeded).